# Getting the wrong value for Time in MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, datetime

I am doing a SELECT query in my node js back end. I have the date and time stored in the Date column in mysql table. However, when I SELECT the Date column to be returned and console.log the value, I notice that the time is 5 hours ahead of what is stored in the database. I had some trouble figuring out how to store the correct time, but I eventually figured that out. It doesn't make sense to me why the date value would change when I retrieve it though. It seems like it should just return the value of the column. Here is my query. The time is stored in the Date column along with the date:

```
const getUserOrders = `SELECT OrderID, Date FROM INVOICE WHERE CustomerID = '${userID}'`;
```

Here is a value stored in my Date column:

```
2020-05-03 00:41:18
```

And here is the value it is returning to me:

```
2020-05-03T05:41:18.000Z
```

Note that the time returned is 5 hours ahead of what I had stored in the database. Also, the formatting appears different (the T and .000Z). Like I mentioned, I had some trouble with the formatting to get MySQL to accept the entered time (from my   node post request), however I did eventually get it to take (I had to format an ISO string). I just can't figure out why it is returning a value other than the one I have stored. Any suggestions sure would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: You are getting the date/time back in the GMT/Zulu time zone. You need to convert it to your locale.

Comment: `2020-05-03T05:41:18.000Z` is `2020-05-03T00:41:18.000 CDT` - I'm assuming you're american